# Controlling DC motor with Pololu shield Arduino

Tags: motor

I'm trying to power 2 DC motors with my Pololu DRV8835. I'm using the code found in [this library](https://github.com/pololu/drv8835-motor-shield). It works as expected BUT ONLY if the whole thing is powered via USB. When I try to power it through the shield with an external battery, the motors only beep. So the program AND the wiring have been tested.

PS.: I've also measured the voltage across the shield (M1A-M1B, M2A-M2B) and they only get like .01 V when powered via external battery. Also I'm using and Arduino Due.

Comment: We are going to need some sort of schematic or wiring diagram before anyone can help you. You can use the built-in schematic tool, or something like a screenshot from http://fritzing.org/download/ or drawn by hand.

Comment: the ESCs are driving 2 seperate BLDC motors (those work) -- https://imgur.com/a/v3P0W

Comment: My guess is that the ESCs are causing you a problem. The Arduino, for sure, is not made to be run off a modulated power supply. The ESCs are going to do very bad things to this circuit.

Comment: In our setup, the arduino only gives the signal to the ESC not power nor does the ESC give power to arduino. The only connection between the arduino and the ESC (apart from the signal) is that they run off of the same lipo battery

Comment: What's the battery pack voltage?

Comment: 7.8V (measured with a multimeter), the package says 7.4

Comment: I think the best thing for you to do at this point is to go through the Arduino Due schematic and make sure your voltages (particularly in the power section) match when you are using battery vs USB power.

Comment: in both cases, when we measured the power pins on the shield, we got 7.8 V (if that's what you meant)

Comment: Don't connect your motors in **series**.

Comment: It didn't work when we connected only one motor either